# Exercise on Expected Value and Variance

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

Let $A$ be a discrete random variable with expected value $a$ and variance $b^2$

$$a:=\Bbb E(A)~~\,\\b^2:=\Bbb{Var}(A)$$

The function F is defined as $$F(x):=\Bbb E[(A-x)^2]$$
Show that $$b^2=(1/2)\cdot \Bbb E(F(A))$$

Hint: Express the function $F(x)$ through $a$, $b^2$ and $A$.

I tried a few things but nothing really worked.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The statement looks mixed up.  What is the definition of V?  Is it F?

Comment: Yes, that is a typing error. i fixed it now

Comment: The statement is still mixed up.  As defined $F(x)$ is a number not a random variable.  Further $F(X)=0$, since $X-X=0$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Presumably the idea is: Take $Y$ to be identically distributed to $X$ but otherwise independent. Then show $b^2 = \frac12 E[(X-Y)^2]$.

Comment: Hint: Expand the definition of $F(x)$ using linearity, invoking what you know about $E[X]$ and $E[X^2]$.

Comment: @Semiclassical then i have $$F(x)=E(A^2)-2xE(A)+x^2=E(A^2)-x^2=Var(F(x))$$, and so $$F(x)+x^2=E(A^2)$$

Comment: I agree with your first equality but don't see how you got to the second or third.

Comment: @Semiclassical my bad it should be, $$()=(^2)−2()+^2$$, so i can write $$a=E(A)=(x^2+E(A^2)-F(x))/2x$$

Comment: Okay. Now express $E(A^2)$ in terms of $a,b$ and determine $F(x)$. Then compute $E[F(x)]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the constants $a$ and $b$ defined as: $a:=\Bbb E(A)$ and $b^2:=\Bbb {Var}(A)$.   It will be useful to note that this means: $\Bbb E(A^2)=b^2+a^2$, by the definition of variance.

$F(x)$, being defined as $\Bbb E((A-x)^2)$, is a function of free variable $x$, with no free occurrence of random variable $A$, since the linear operation (expectation) binds that random variable.

$$\begin{align}F(x)&=\Bbb E(A^2-2Ax+x^2)\\&=\text{a function of free variable $x$, and constants $a,b$}\end{align}$$

$F(A)$ is that function with all free occurrences of $x$ replaced by $A$.   This replacement must occur *after* the evaluation of the expectation to avoid collision with the bound occurrence. In short:$$\begin{align}F(A) &= \text{a function of random variable $A$, and constants $a,b$}\end{align}$$

The random variable $A$ occurs free in this function, so we take its expectation as we normally do.

$$\begin{align}\Bbb E(F(A))&=\\&~~\vdots\\&=2b^2\end{align}$$

And so it is done.

Answer (score 1):

You are told $\mathbb{E}[A] = a$, $Var[A] = b^2$, from which we obtain $\mathbb{E}[A^2] = a^2+b^2$

**Assumption:** To clarify notations, will assume x to be an instance of Random Variable X. For clarity, I will mark this as $F(X=x)$ instead of $F(x)$.
Further, since we are not told in $F(x)$, what the expectation is over, we will presume this to be over A. In this notation, we will write $$F(X=x) := \mathbb{E}_{A}[(A-x)^2]$$

Then we can write:
\begin{align*}
F(X=x)&=\mathbb{E}_{A}[(A-x)^2]\\ &= \mathbb{E}_{A}[A^2] -2 \mathbb{E}_{A}[Ax]+\mathbb{E}_{A}[x^2]\\&= \mathbb{E}_{A}[A^2] -2x \mathbb{E}_{A}[A]+x^2\\& = a^2+b^2-2ax+x^2
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_X[F(X=x)]&=\mathbb{E}_X[a^2+b^2-2ax+x^2]\\
&=a^2+b^2-2a\mathbb{E}_X[X=x]+\mathbb{E}_X[(X=x)^2]\\
\mathbb{E}_A[F(A)]&=a^2+b^2-2a\mathbb{E}_A[A]+\mathbb{E}_A[A^2]\\
&=a^2+b^2-2a\cdot a+(a^2+b^2)\\
&=2b^2\\
\end{align*}
which proves $b^2=\frac{\mathbb{E}_A[F(A)]}{2}$ as required

**Observation:**
The question is rather unclear in the first part on how X and A are related. For instance, if one uses $\mathbb{E}_{A|X=x}(\cdot)$ instead of $\mathbb{E}_{A}(\cdot)$ for $F(X=x)$, then, one ends up with an answer of 0 for the given question. Thus one has to assume that x is a free variable (as @Graham Kemp points out in comments)

Comment: Should it be $\mathbb{E}_X[F(X)]$? (and similarly for other appearences of $x$)

Comment: indeed. Thank you @Semiclassical

Comment: There is no need to assume that $x$ is anything other than a free variable which, in this case, is replaced by $A$ at a certain point.  Thus I'd write it like so: $$\begin{align}\Bbb E(F(A))&=\Bbb E([F(x)]_{x=A})\\&=\Bbb E([\Bbb E((A-x)^2)]_{x=A})\\&=\Bbb E([\Bbb E(A^2-2xA+x^2)]_{x=A})\\&=\Bbb E([\Bbb E(A^2)-2x\Bbb E(A)+x^2]_{x=A})\\&=\Bbb E([b^2+a^2-2ax+x^2]_{x=A})&\because~&\Bbb E(A^2)=\Bbb {Var}(A)+\Bbb E(A)^2\\&=b^2+a^2-2a\Bbb E(A)+\Bbb E(A^2)\\&=2b^2\\\therefore\quad b^2&=\tfrac 12\Bbb E(F(A))\end{align}$$ However, this is the same end result, so... *yeah*.